# WPF Binding not being updated

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

On my View model, I have the following property:

```
public Visibility IsModelBusy { get; set; }
```

I have a long processing task that does:

```
private void DoSomething(object obj)
{
    IsModelBusy = Visibility.Visible;
    OnPropertyChanged("IsModelBusy"); 
    DoHeavyWork();
    IsModelBusy = Visibility.Collapsed;
    OnPropertyChanged("IsModelBusy");
}
```

I have a UI element that is bound to `IsModelBusy`:

```
<Border Visibility="{Binding IsModelBusy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
...
</Border>
```

**PROBLEM**
My Border never gets visible and the main window hangs while the heavy task is ongoing (I can't run this in a background thread)
I tried wrapping the property changed call in an action passed to a Dispatcher with no luck, the problem still persists.

Now if I do this:

```
private void DoSomething(object obj)
{
    IsModelBusy = Visibility.Visible;
    OnPropertyChanged("IsModelBusy"); 
    MessageBox.Show("What the...");  <=========
    DoHeavyWork();
    IsModelBusy = Visibility.Collapsed;
    OnPropertyChanged("IsModelBusy");
}
```

With the introduction of the `MessageBox`, the UI seems to process the property changed events and update correctly.

**QUESTION**
Without using background tasks, how can I force the UI to process the `PropertyChanged` events?

Comment: Have you tried setting `Binding Mode` to `Two-Way`? I believe Visibility is default `One-Way`.

Comment: > I can't run this in a background thread - can you explain, why?

Comment: who's calling DoSomething()?

Comment: @Bob Two-way binding to Visibility does not make any sense.

Comment: @Dennis Multithreading is not an option - this is a requirement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this a lot, I finally found the answers to my questions:

> With the introduction of the MessageBox, the UI seems to process the property changed events and update correctly.

The message box forces the application to process its message queue, hence processing the property changed events and updating the UI.

> Without using background tasks, how can I force the UI to process the PropertyChanged events?

There is no way around this - I kept the message box solution to force the UI to process all events

Answer (score 5):

You're blocking the UI thread with your `DoHeavyWork()`.

The Dispatcher cannot process any other operations (such as refreshing the UI) because it's busy executing your code.

Put that in a background thread.

Comment: -1. This does not answer my questionings at all. I know that `DoHeavyWork` is blocking my workflow. What I am after is why does `MessageBox` force the UI to refresh?

Comment: There is not technical argument about not using threads - the only problem are my requirements. I can't use multi-threading by requirement - isn't this a clear enough reason?

Comment: @GETah what kind of requirement is that? is this an exam or something?